# How to get connection from EntityFrameworkCore DBContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get connection from EntityFrameworkCore DBContext to invoke custom sql in the same transaction. However returned connection is in closed state.

```
SqlCommand sql_cmd = new SqlCommand("...");
sql_cmd.Connection = (SqlConnection)context.Database.GetDbConnection();
```

What am I missing? How should it be done properly?

Comment: There are some correct ways to perform a custom query https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: There's no transaction. DbContext is neither a database connection nor a transaction scope.It's designed to work *disconnected* and doesn't even maintain an open connection. An *internal* transaction is used only when `SaveChanges` is called to persist all accumulated changes at once.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What transaction do you refer to? If you want to execute ADO.NET code why involve EF Core? Or to reverse this - why not use `FromSqlRaw` if there's a complex query or a stored procedure or function involved?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos or in some other cases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: Have you tried to implement the "generic repository" *anti*pattern? And then added an explicit transaction to get back the UoW functionality you lost by not using `SaveChanges` ?

Comment: I am not refering to sql transaction only to context.Database.BeginTransaction().

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy that's not a different case. That's an explicit call to start a transaction. EF core doesn't need that in the first place. Code like that *causes* performance issues and quite likely caused the OP's problem as well

Comment: @mwal that's a SQL transaction. Which isn't needed by EF Core and has to be started explicitly. Which suggests you aren't using EF Core in the mainstream way, and probably shouldn't be using it in the first place (if you really need ADO.NET)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos can't you perform a set of operations in EntityFrameworkCore?

Comment: @Roman Ryzhiy there is no Database.SqlQuery() in EFCore.

Comment: @mwal that's what `SaveChanges` does. Perform *all* operations in a single, atomic batch. What is your *actual* question? What are you trying to do? Why can't you do that with EF Core itself? Whatever it is, there are solutions to this already, that don't sacrifice performance, scaleability or consistency

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos if I do some data change is it already available for selects from the same context even before SaveChanges and before all changes are commited to the world?

Comment: @mwal what does that mean??? You can execute queries at any time. If the data is in the database, it's returned. A DbContext is *not* a connection either, it's a Unit-of-Work, supposed to exist only for as long as necessary. So there shouldn't be any need to save data "before" saving ... the data. You create the DbContext, read the data you need, modify it, SaveChanges, Disposed. In an ASP.NET Core app that would give you a "transaction"-per-request without actually needing transactions

Comment: @mwal but there is `FromSqlRaw` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: @Roman Ryzhiy I want to return scalar value, not en entity. How do I do that.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy you can write a LINQ query that returns a scalar value, or use `FromSqlRaw` to do the same. `FromSqlRaw` doesn't have to return an entity

Comment: LINQ query worked fine. Thanks.